# cgexec not placing child process in correct cgroup

Tags: debian, cgroups

I have made two cgroups:

```
sudo cgcreate -g cpu,memory:rustserver
sudo cgset -r memory.max=150000000 rustserver
sudo cgset -r cpu.max=25000 rustserver

sudo cgcreate -g cpu,memory:pyexecutor
sudo cgset -r memory.max=150000000 pyexecutor
sudo cgset -r cpu.max=25000 pyexecutor
```

This is my `/etc/cgrules.conf` file:

```
*:target/debug/python-executor cpu,memory pyexecutor
*:target/debug/rust-api cpu,memory rustserver
```

I execute the following command:
`sudo cgexec target/debug/rust-api`

Because of the documentation of the [cgexex](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cgexec) command

> -g : defines control groups in which the task will be run. controllers is a list of controllers and path is the relative
> path to control groups in the given controllers list. This flag can be
> used multiple times to define multiple pairs of lists of controllers
> and relative paths. Instead of the list of all mounted controllers,
> wildcard b"*b" can be used.
>
> **If this option is not used then cgexec will automatically place the
> task to the right cgroup based on /etc/cgrules.conf.**
>
> --sticky If running the task command with this option, the daemon of service cgred (cgrulesengd process) does not change both the task of
> **the command and the children tasks. Without this option, the daemon
> does not change the task of the command but it changes the children
> tasks to the right cgroup based on /etc/cgrules.conf automatically.**

I expect that `target/debug/python-executor` which is a child process executed by `rust-api` gets placed in it's own cgroup. But this child process also comes in the cgroup `rustserver`.

I want my main-app (rust-api) to have it's own cgroup. And rust-api spawns multiple processes called python-executor. These child processes should come in `pyexecutor` cgroup.

Running `sudo cgclassify <pid of a python-executor>` does place the process in the correct `pyexecutor` cgroup.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution:

```
watch -n 5 'sudo cgclassify $(pgrep -x python-executor | tr "\n" " ")'
```

Execute cgclassify every 5 seconds to add the python-executor to the correct cgroup based on `etc/cgrules.conf`.